# Find and remove text from input value string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Our form has a hidden `input` that contains all the required values we send to the server for server-side validation. This is formed of a comma-separated string:

i.e. `<input type="hidden" value="name,address,telephone,email">`

We now have new inputs (i.e. website) that appear on a radio button check and I can successfully add these to the `value=""` string:

```
var nowReq = $('input[name="required"]').val();
if ($('#website').is(':checked')) {
    $('input[name="required"]').val(nowReq + ',website');
}
```

But when a different radio is checked, I can't get it to remove `,website` from the string.

I believe I need to grab the string, split it by comma, find and remove `website` and then re-join the string, but I'm not sure how to implement this (or if this is even the best way):

```
if ($('#fax').is(':checked')) {
    var splitReq = nowReq.split(',');
    // Something goes here?
    $('input[name="required"]').val(nowReq2);
}
```

Comment: Create a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.indexOf(searchValue);` and `string.replace(oldValue, newValue);` to search and remove non-selected elements or better pass *Regular expression* in the first parameter of `string.replace(regex, newValue)`:

**Non-regex Example:**

```
var nowReq = $('input[name="required"]').val();
if ($('#website').is(':checked')) {
    nowReq = nowReq + ',website';
}
else {
    if(string.indexOf(',website') > -1) // If website is the last element
        nowReq = nowReq.replace(',website', '');
    else if(string.indexOf('website,') > -1) // If website is not the last element
        nowReq = nowReq.replace('website,', '');
}

$('input[name="required"]').val(nowReq);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to remove the last element in your array and join it with the ',' character :

```
splitReq.pop();
$('input[name="required"]').val(splitReq.join(','));
```

Comment: who said its gonna be the last elemet

Comment: well, since he just added the value at the end of the string, it's always going to be the last element...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var splitReq = nowReq.split(',website').join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you avoid parsing the value string, and simply recalculate the value on the change of the relevant `input` elements; the following is a demonstrative example because of the lack of information presented in the question (a more specific example could be provided if we can see your HTML, and current jQuery, rather than a description of it):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    var requiredString = $('input[type="checkbox"]').map(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            return this.value;
        }
    }).get().join(',');
    $('input[name="required"]').val(requiredString);
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QZ6V9/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

the following would work in most cases:

```
var s = "name,address,telephone,email";
s = s.replace(",address", "").replace("address,", "").replace("address", "");
```